# How can I install / unistall applications using android code?

Tags: android

Is it possible to install / uninstall applications on device by android code without user interaction ?

Answer (score 2):

yeah it's possible You need to use `Process` and `Runtime` for execute `adb` command in Android grammatically.Suppose you wanna install an apk then you need to run `./adb install ~/Desktop/apkname`.Similarly you need to use `./adb install` command for this.

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./adb install 'complete path of your apk file'");
```

Hope this will work Good luck.